# Win32 SendKeys.SendWait("keys") to minimized application

Tags: c#, winapi, silent-installer

I would like to use `SendKeys.SendWait("keys")` to send some keystrokes to a minimized or non-visible application.

Experimentally, it only appears to work when the application I'm sending it to has the focus and is visible. I tried giving the application the focus when it was not visible, to no avail. I'm hoping I've missed something. **Is there any way to do this?**

Background:

I"m trying to force a 3rd-party install package that does not support silent installation to be as quiet and automated as possible. I contacted the folks who created installer, and they didn't enable silent installs and won't be releasing a new one.

The installer is an InstallAnywhere package that spins up Java AWT. Because of this, Spy++ won't show me IDs for buttons. The only thing I get is the handle for the main window, which leads me to believe I have to send keys using `SendKeys.SendWait("keys")` to get the automation I need.

I can get it to walk through the installation using `SendKeys.SendWait("%n")` (for "Alt-N" making it press the "Next" button), but I want to hide the window. Because I can't tell when it's done with a particular stage, I'm polling it periodically, and pressing the appropriate key. It's a huge hack, but I haven't found a better option. The problem is, I don't want to minimize then restore for each of these keypresses. There's got to be a better way than this, right?

Using C# .NET 4.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately keyboard input goes to the active window, so anything that simulates keyboard input will behave the same way.

If they added Accessibility hooks, then you can use the [UI automation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx). Here is a quick sample from [Raymond's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/08/10409196.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't look like they added Accessibility hooks to the installer. Thanks for the tip though.